# Firebase dynamic links does not work on iOS gmail

Tags: ios, firebase-dynamic-links

I have setup a firebase dynamic link like explained here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sFPo296OQqk

When I tap on my dynamic link via Notes app, it opens my app as expected.

But when I tap on the dynamic link via gmail app on iOS - it just open the Chrome Browser on iOS and redirects me to the fallback web URL. It does not open the app.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the iOS Gmail app allows you to select whether links will open in Chrome or Safari. When Chrome is selected, Universal Links (which is what Firebase dynamic links piggyback on) do not work. You'll need to somehow open a web page with the link and then present a button for users to click that will open your app. At Branch.io, we use our [deepviews](https://branch.io/features/#deepviews) feature for this.

For more info, see [this list](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/universal-app-links/support/ios/#appsbrowsers-that-support-universal-links) of apps that support Universal Links.

Answer (score 1):

You should follow the below link.This will definitely fulfill your query.

[Firebase dynamic link doesnt work in safari swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47414376/firebase-dynamic-link-doesnt-work-in-safari-swift/47424706#47424706)